# how to make for loop for buttons in easy way?

Tags: javafx

As it is my first application in javafx and trying to make a simple calculator. I want to know how I can make this for loop in easy way :

```
for(int i=1; i<10; i++){
    Button bt1 = new Button();       
    bt1.setText("1");    
    bt1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override 
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("1");
        }
    });
    i 1;
}
```

And how to get this buttons in `VBox`.

Comment: You already have a for loop in which you make buttons.  It looks pretty easy to me.  So I'm not sure what you are asking for here because (a) you already seem to have your answer and (b) there isn't an easier way of accomplishing it.  Perhaps what you are really asking is the last part of your question "how to get this buttons in VBox", which is to write `VBox vbox = new VBox();` before the loop and `vbox.getChildren().add(bt1)` inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks , I think that what I asked about . But , when I tried to run it takes lots of time , I do not know why.

Comment: It should be practically instantaneous, so I don't know what your performance issue is.  If you need help debugging performance issues, you need to supply an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that somebody could just copy and paste your entire (minimal) application to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it takes a lot of time to do that 
but as jewels said it should be very quick in doing that, i'm working with javafx since 9 months at work on a computer that is not very performant  and, as i understand  it, in the calculator you would have 10 buttons for numbers from 0 to 9, i'd code it like this:

```
VBox vboxForButtons = new VBox();
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    Button btnNumber = new Button();
    btnNumber.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    btnNumber.setOnAction((ActionEvent)->{
        System.out.println(btnNumber.getText());
    });
    vboxForButtons.getChildren().add(btnNumber);
}
```

In alternative to this, for small and slight applications i advice you to use the SceneBuilder tool linking directly the objects that you drag in the window to an FXML event in the code.

I hope this answer will help you.

Comment: Thanks alot ,                                                                                                I want to ask you about any good source that I can learn SceneBuilder from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using the following code.

```
        VBox vbox = new VBox();   //create new VBox instance
        vbox.setMinWidth(500);    //set minimum width, dont think you'd need this. 

        for(int i=1; i<10; i++){
            Button btn = new Button();   
            btn.setMinWidth(200);
            btn.setMinHeight(50);
            btn.setText("Button" + i);    
            btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override 
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    System.out.println(btn.getText()); //Or "1" as in your code
                }
            });
            vbox.getChildren().add(btn); //add button to your VBox
        }

        root.getChildren().add(vbox); //root of your pane
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); //primaryStage is your stage, scene is the current scene
        primaryStage.show();
```

**Edit**

Reading the comments in your question about performance issue, this will not fix any of it. I have basically written the same code that you've used above, and added VBox creation and adding Button to it, because from the question it sounded like you needed help with creating VBox and adding Buttons to it.